# Symfony rewrite nginx

Tags: symfony, nginx

I'm running with Symfony 3.4, and I already configure my nginx to works with directly http://example.org/my-route instead of http://example.org/app.php/my-route

```
server {
    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        # bla bla bla
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        # bla bla bla
    }
}
```

But now I'd like to redirect user visiting my website with http://example.org/app.php/my-route to http://example.org/my-route

I try to create an new rewrite, but I got loop redirect

```
rewrite ^/app.php(.*) /$1 permanent;
```

Should I only add a header() in my app.php ?

```
if (strpos($request->getUri(), $request->getHost().'/app.php') !== false) {
    $uri = str_replace($request->getHost().'/app.php', $request->getHost(), $request->getUri());
    header('Location: ' . $uri, true, 301);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid a loop, you need to identify when `/app.php` is the original request, rather than the same URI generated by the `try_files` statement.

The original request can be found in the `$request_uri` variable, which can be tested using an `if` block.

For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/app.php(.+)$) { return 301 $1; }
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.